# phpMyAdmin Old Version (2.6.1) Encoding

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, hebrew

I have an access to a MySql Server, but I can only access to that sites phpMyAdmin.
The problem is the the DB old Hebrew characters, and when I export or view them it in the wrong encoding.

Is there any way to export the data and set the encoding?

Comment: Describe in more detail what you're doing and what is happening.

Comment: I'm trying to export the database in order to import it to another MySql server. But during the export process the .sql file generated is in the wrong encoding but I can see an option to set the it's encoding...

Comment: So? are you trying this encoding option?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little bit late, but I guess it still worth mentioning.
There are several things which you should check:

1. Database encoding is set to `utf8_general_ci`
2. When you are outputting the data, make sure it's within the `<body>` and you have set an encoding to your page in the `<head>`: `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

Comment: Thanks! The job is finished by now, but it's nice to know! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be any of help :)